# Didn't caped Mario turn to Super Mario after damage?

Tags: super-mario-world

I bought Super Mario World on WiiU and I remember in the SNES version of Super Mario World, taking damage as Caped Mario/Fire Mario would return you to Super Mario, not small Mario.

The WiiU version is the US version. Was this something in the PAL only version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit of a weird topic, because what exactly happens to Mario upon taking damage with a power-up has indeed changed across different releases of games. I found this reference on the Super Mario Wiki page of [Super Mario Bros. 3](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Bros._3):

> In international releases of this game, after players obtain a power-up that is greater than a Super Mushroom, any injury will turn them back to their super form, like in every platformer *Mario* game after *Super Mario World*. In the original Japanese Famicom release, any hit reduces the player back to small form, like in *Super Mario Bros.*, *Super Mario Bros: The Lost Levels* and *Super Mario World*.

So there are two behaviours here:

1. Getting hit with a power-up puts you back into Small form.

   - *Super Mario Bros.* (1)
   - *Super Mario Bros: The Lost Levels*
   - *Super Mario Bros. 3* (JPN version only)
   - *Super Mario World*
2. Getting hit with a power-up loses the power-up, but retains Super form.

   - *Super Mario Bros. 3* (all non-JPN versions)
   - Every other Mario game with the Small-Super-Power system

[This video I found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IFRMEup1P8&t=3m40s) seems to confirm that, yes, you get pushed all the way back to Small upon taking damage with a Cape. And I see no indication on [the wiki's SMW page](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_World) that any regional differences changed the system.

Answer (score 2):

Like Toomai, I can't find any SNES version of Super Mario World that has the behaviour that you recall, but I've found that the GBA versions do.

> When the player gets hurt with Cape or Fire power, they won't become small and need to use the item in reserve (if any); instead, they will become Super Mario/Luigi and keep the reserve item until they are hit again.

(source: [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_World:_Super_Mario_Advance_2#Gameplay_changes))

I also tried it myself to confirm.